# Loading content from subdomain in jQuery Dialog with ReverseProxy and ARR

Tags: jquery, asp.net, regex, iis-7, reverse-proxy

I have two asp.net IIS sites on same server

1. apps.mycompany.org
2. mycompany.org

Both has separate contents. 
I want to show one page from apps.mycompany.org (say appsPage1.aspx) inside mycompany.org site.
Page is required to be shown inside jQuery Dialog box.

I know the same origin policy and possible solutions like jsonp etc. First we thought to do it simply using iframe but it was causing other look & feel as well some functionality related issues. So in this case we have decided to go with reverse proxy.

Wanted to know what are correct steps to achieve this via IIS 7's ARR & ReverseProxy ? Can  anyone help with the correct steps of configurations of it ?

Specially I am confused for proper regex of inbound and outbound rules. In which site I am suppose to write it and some hint how it will look like.